# "Weighting" the amount of a SimPy Resource to use for a process

Tags: python, simpy

I would like to send orders to a Resource in SimPy, which specify a quantity of products that the Resource would manufacture.

My issue is that when I send an order of 100 quantity, the resource is only utilized for the 1 order rather than utilized for the 100 quantity.  Is there a way to model this in SimPy?

I understand how to use Containers and Stores rather than a Resource `Resource`, but for my larger application I would like this to be a resource since different product inventory levels would be stored in `Container` levels.  This resource would be shared among multiple products.

Here is the mocked up simple example for my question above.  Thanks!
If I could add `plan_for_hour_x` as the parameter for `processing_capacity.request(plan_for_hour_x)`, that would solve my problem, but that does not seem to be possible.

```
import simpy
env = simpy.Environment()
processing_capacity_per_hour = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1000)
DEMAND_IN_HOUR_1 = 100

def production_plan(env, processing_capacity, plan_for_hour_x): 
    yield env.timeout(1)
    print(f'The current time is {env.now}')
    with processing_capacity.request() as req:
        yield req
        print(f'Resources in use 1: {processing_capacity.count}')
        yield env.timeout(1)
            
env.process(production_plan(env, 
                            processing_capacity_per_hour, 
                            DEMAND_IN_HOUR_1))
env.run(until=5)
print(f'The ending time is {env.now}')

>>> The current time is 1
>>> Resources in use 1: 1
>>> The ending time is 5
```

Comment: I'm finding that I can do the `request()` and `release()` method rather than to use with `resource.request() as req`.  However, I'm still working on how to automate the 100 request and release statements since DEMAND_IN_HOUR_1 = 100.

Comment: The solution on this other thread worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396024/resource-not-releasing-in-simpy-what-am-i-doing-wrong.  Scroll down to "Update based on Stefan Scherfke's comment, is to pass the req explicitly to the new process:".  Therefore, this works for now.  I do wonder whether there is a simpler solution that I overlooked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to seize 100 resources in one grab then do this

```
import simpy
from simpy.events import AllOf
env = simpy.Environment()
processing_capacity_per_hour = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1000)
DEMAND_IN_HOUR_1 = 100

def production_plan(env, processing_capacity, plan_for_hour_x): 
    yield env.timeout(1)
    print(f'The current time is {env.now}')

    req_list = [processing_capacity.request() for _ in range(plan_for_hour_x)]
    
    yield AllOf(env, req_list)
    print(f'Resources in use: {processing_capacity.count}')
    yield env.timeout(1)

    for req in req_list:
        processing_capacity.release(req)

    print(f'Resources in use: {processing_capacity.count}')
            
env.process(production_plan(env, 
                            processing_capacity_per_hour, 
                            DEMAND_IN_HOUR_1))
env.run(until=5)
print(f'The ending time is {env.now}')
```

this will print

```
The current time is 1
Resources in use: 100
Resources in use: 0
The ending time is 5
```

but it sounds like a container might be a better choice over a resource

Comment: Thanks!  This makes a lot more sense.